# Configuring Frame Relay using a Switch Simulation - Packet Tracer

Tags: cisco, packet

I have the following set up in Packet Tracer:

[image]

I am trying to configure frame-relay between the RTR-EDGE router, the RTR_ENG router and the RTR_SAL router using a frame-relay switch simulation (the cloud). I have used the following commands:

```
RTR_EDGE(config)#int s3/0
RTR_EDGE(config-if)#encap frame-relay
RTR_EDGE(config-if)#frame-relay map ip 172.20.1.109 101 broadcast
RTR_EDGE(config-if)#frame-relay map ip 172.20.1.113 102 broadcast
RTR_EDGE(config-if)#ip address 172.20.1.117 255.255.255.252
RTR_EDGE(config-if)#frame-relay lmi-type cisco
RTR_EDGE(config-if)#no shutdown

RTR_ENG(config)#int s0/0
RTR_ENG(config-if)#encap frame-relay
RTR_ENG(config-if)#frame-relay map ip 172.20.1.117 200 broadcast
RTR_EDGE(config-if)#ip address 172.20.1.109 255.255.255.252
RTR_ENG(config-if)#frame-relay lmi-type cisco
RTR_ENG(config-if)#no shutdown

RTR_SAL(config)#int s0/0
RTR_SAL(config-if)#encap frame-relay
RTR_SAL(config-if)#frame-relay map ip 172.20.1.117 200 broadcast
RTR_SAL(config-if)#ip address 172.20.1.113 255.255.255.252
RTR_SAL(config-if)#frame-relay lmi-type cisco
RTR_SAL(config-if)#no shutdown
```

And the circuit appears in the map of each router:

```
RTR_EDGE#show frame-relay map
Serial3/0 (up): ip 172.20.1.109 dlci 101, static, broadcast, CISCO, status defined, active
Serial3/0 (up): ip 172.20.1.113 dlci 102, static, broadcast, CISCO, status defined, active
```

However, neither of the three routers can ping each other? Does anyone have any ideas as to why not? I have looked at a few tutorials on the internet and their commands are the same as mine, however theirs works and mine doesn't..

Any help would be appreciated! Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Do you have the routes to each other router?

I don't know if it is necessary to add the routes to your frame-relay configuration, but you should check like this:

```
RTR_EDGE# show ip route 172.20.1.109
RTR_EDGE# show ip route 172.20.1.113
RTR_ENG# show ip route 172.20.1.117
RTR_SAL# show ip route 172.20.1.117
```

Answer (score 1):

Your endpoints are on a different subnet to each other, if you decrease the subnet mask to a /27 (255.255.255.224 in non-CIDR terms) you should have more luck.